# Segmentation fault (core dumped) How to troubleshoot proprietary executable?

Tags: fedora, rhel, debugging, segmentation-fault

I'm working with some proprietary software. It runs OK on RHEL 7, but on Fedora 26 it segfaults.

`[nnieto@doge PropietarySoftware] $ bin/command
sysname warning: fedora only partially supported.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

I tried `ldd` and there are no missing shared libraries in both RHEL and Fedora. How can I troubleshoot this if I don't have access to the source code?

Comment: Presumably you could ask your proprietary support...

Comment: As @drewbenn suggests, `strace`.  Try `strace -fo /tmp/foo bin/command` and then review the /tmp/foo file contents, particularly towards the end.

Comment: @drewbenn `strace` doesn't usually help with segfaults. It tells you what system calls the process is making, but a segfault is triggered by an invalid manipulation inside the process. `strace` lets you know the last external thing the process did, and sometimes that can suggest a workaround (find a way to avoid doing that thing and hope that the crash was related).